# A suitable word of a man who helps

Tags: vocabulary

What is the apt word for the man who listens to the request and helps?

Comment: "Assistant" is a general term, but could you be more specific in the type of help you want to refer to?

Comment: He was (is always) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Someone who is kind, generous or helpful**

**Synonyms**

**saint [noun]**

someone who is very kind, patient, and helpful

**gem [noun]**

someone who is special in some way, especially because they are useful or helpful

**angel [noun]**

mainly spoken a very kind person

**star [noun]**

informal someone who does something kind and helpful

**love [noun]**

british someone who you like very much because they are kind

**Samaritan [noun]**

someone who is willing to help you when you are in trouble

**fairy godmother [noun]**

a woman who likes helping people

**saviour [noun]**

a person who saves someone or something from trouble or danger

**treasure [noun]**

informal someone who is very helpful and kind

**do-gooder [noun]**

someone who always tries to help people, especially people who are poor or in trouble. This word is used as a criticism, to suggest that their help is unnecessary or unsuitable.

Source: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/someone-who-is-kind-generous-or-helpful